# ThreeJS cant move camera

Tags: three.js

Im trying to move camera by changing its world matrix. But it doesen't seem to work. No matter what the camera wont move.

```
camera.matrixAutoUpdate = false
camera.matrixWorld = portal_view(camera,port1_quad,port2_quad)
```

i have tried using the matrixupdate = true but still nothing. What am i douing wrong ?

```
function portal_view(camera, src_portal, dst_portal) {
                var inverse_view_to_source = new THREE.Matrix4().getInverse(camera.matrix).multiply(src_portal.matrix);
                var new_mat = dst_portal.matrix.clone().multiply(inverse_view_to_source);
                new_mat.makeRotationY(3.14);

                return new_mat;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

`matrixWorld` of an object is computed from its `position`, `quaternion` and `scale`. You cant directly change the 'matrixWorld' of an object. In other words, if you change the `matrixWorld`, the change wont be reflected on `position` of the object. You have to change the `position` of the camera.

What you can do is, extract the `translation` and `rotation` from the matrix and change the camera `position` and `quaternion` according to it.

Comment: camera.updateMatrix() would update the matrix and position and rotation would change. Now i just need to figure out what is wrong with the equation.

Comment: `Camera.updateMatrix()` or `Object3D.updateMatrix()` wont change the `position` or `quaternion` of an object. It will just update the current transformation matrix using current `position`, `quaternion` and `scale`.

Comment: changing the matrixWorld works perfectly. You just cant call updates or you'll lose the changes. Issue was actually in the portal_view function. ThreeJS framework is bit clunky so it wont always change the values if you call the inverse or multiply or rotation. I had to mess around with them so that they would actually start to work. 

Why changeing matrix world works is because on the background camera is nothing more than    glUniformMatrix4fv(uniform_v_inv, 1, GL_FALSE,viewMatrix); or something like that. ThreeJS camera is just a interface to somewhat make it easyer to use.